# Radio hearing when connect axefx3 to return of tube amply

Tags: amplifiers, amplification

I have a problem when I use my amply as an amplifier only bypassing tonestack. When I connect a guitar in the front input of amply all works well and I didn't hear any radio station. But when I connect the same cable into the return jack of the same amply, I start hearing a radio station. How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: We have a number of close votes for "not enough detail." Could someone clarify what extra detail is needed?

Comment: The description doesn't explain how the modeller is plugged in each of these setups.

Comment: Hi there, it's a little unclear, is amply an abbreviation? Or a name of a brand? Either way, a generic answer may be that an amp input will have simple circuitry designed to block RF interference (eg. radio) on the input stage, before going through the first preamp stage and tone stack. By return jack, you mean FX return? If so, depending on the amp, that most likely won't have the same RF blocking circuitry, as that problem is less common when returning from FX devices. Similarly, the FX loop will probably be after preampfification, so it is designed for a larger signal than a guitar input.